# Adding custom constant to system constants

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm wonder if here is any way to add custom constant to system constants.

For example in my coding I often uses such code:

```
VB.NET
Private Sub myform_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F3 Or (e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.F) Then
        search(mytextbox.Text.Trim)
    End If
End Sub

C#
private void myform_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F3 | (e.Control & e.KeyCode == Keys.F)) {
    search(mytextbox.Text.Trim);
    }
}
```

Idea is to add new element to Enum Keys, say "Find"
So I would be able to do this:

```
VB.NET    
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Find Then
    search(mytextbox.Text.Trim)
End If

C#
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Find) {
    search(mytextbox.Text.Trim);
}
```

Of course I would first replace keystrokes Keys.F3 and e.Control+Keys.F to Keys.Find in some lower level "ProcessCmdKey" on Applicaton level like this:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean

    If keyData = Keys.F3 Then
        msg.WParam = CType(Keys.Find, IntPtr)
        keyData = Keys.Find
    End If

    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

So, question is:
Could Keys.Find be added to Keys constants and if do - how?

Comment: Then this seem's really dont go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because you don't control the source of the data (`e.KeyCode`).  Let's say you could add a new value to the enum how could you tell windows to start sending you this particular new value when it detects the combination of control and keys?

Comment: I mention that. I will override ProcessCmdKey from keys pressed to keys wanted.

Comment: Do you know what ProcessCmdKeys can do? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx

Comment: Of course, I use it among others for changing/replacing keys: If keyData = Keys.Enter Then
                keyData = Keys.Down
                msg.WParam = CType(Keys.Down, IntPtr)
            End If When I press Keys.Enter I catch e.KeyCode for Keys.Down in my form!